# Laravel artisan route:cache causes Erroneous data Exception

Tags: php, laravel

Running the command: `php artisan route:cache` produces the following execption:

```
Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Symfony\Component\Routing\CompiledRoute'
```

Running: `php artisan route:clear` fixes it

I'd like to know how I can fix this so I can cache my routes.

Comment: Remove any closures (inline functions) in routes, if you have.

Comment: I have no closures in my routes file

Comment: Facing the same issue with no closures in routes.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find a workaround that you could share?

Comment: Not yet, im planning to reclone into a fresh directory and see what happens

Comment: Just ran into the same issue, any solutions yet?

Comment: None yet, still getting the exact same error no matter what.

Comment: Tried downgrading symfony/routing to v4.2.0 to see if that would help but I couldn't as the version was too low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bunch of figuring things out. I found that Apache2 was still using an older version of PHP even though the CLI version was up to date.

After uninstalling all older versions of php and reconfiguring Apache2 to use the latest version fixed this issue.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: This only works until the route cache is created again

Comment: every artisan command showing                                                                               
  Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Compiled  
  Route'  ERROR  after changing php version

Answer (score 11):

For me, this error was solved by deleting the following path files:

```
\bootstrap\cache
```

Comment: You wiped out your cache, but I bet the problem would show up again as soon as you ran `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: fwiw, deleting /bootstrap/cache/routes.php worked for me. including running php artisan route:cache afterward.

Answer (score 6):

I hope you are using same php version for CLI and also for the project . Also PHP 7.4 routing cache doesn't work with php 7.3 .

Answer (score 0):

When trying to update Laravel, the same problem arose.
The only way that helped me was to downgrade the version of symfony/routing to v4.2.0 (I had v 4.4.3)

`composer require symfony/routing:v4.2.0`

Comment: Tried downgrading symfony/routing to v4.2.0 to see if that would help but I couldn't as the symfony/routing version was too low for the current version of Laravel (6.9.0).